# QGIS crashes when toggle editing for child layer in QgsDualView

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, gui

The crash occurs for:

- Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
- QGIS 3.4.2

For reproduce the crash, I use the data from Natural Earth Data:

- https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip
- https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_populated_places_simple.zip

Here the code:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
for ml in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if ml.name() == 'ne_110m_admin_0_countries':
        layer = ml
        par = ml.id()
    elif ml.name() == 'ne_110m_populated_places_simple':
        chi = ml.id()

rel = QgsRelation()
rel.setReferencingLayer(chi)
rel.setReferencedLayer(par)
rel.addFieldPair('adm0_a3', 'ADM0_A3')
rel.setId('countries_places')
rel.setName('Relation beetween places & countries')
if rel.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().relationManager().addRelation(rel)

dialog = QgsDualView()
dialog.init(layer, canvas)
dialog.setView(QgsDualView.AttributeEditor)
dialog.show()
```

In a QGIS Project with the two vector layers loaded, the code above generates a `QgsDualView` dialogue type and sets up a `QgsRelation` between vector layers.

When I click on the toggle Editing button on the `QgsRelationEditorWidget`, QGIS crashes, even if the relation is set manually. What could be a problem?

Comment: Getting the same issue on my Windows 10 and GIS 3.0.3. Have you tried sending a bug report?

Comment: No, I haven't take the time to transfer and re-verify my old redmine tickets to github. And I post it here for verify if its a code error or a qgis error.